# How to do mandatory fields in prismic.io CMS?

Tags: reactjs, paas, prismic.io

I'm using Prismic.io as a headless CMS and bringing content into my React front end. How do I set up a content type so that fields are mandatory?

Here's what I have so far...

```
{
  "Main" : {
    "uid" : {
      "type" : "UID",
      "config" : {
        "placeholder" : "UID"
      }
    },
    "image" : {
      "type" : "Image"
    },
    "title" : {
      "type" : "StructuredText",
      "config" : {
        "single" : "heading1",
        "placeholder" : "Title..."
      }
    },
    "description" : {
      "type" : "StructuredText",
      "config" : {
        "multi" : "paragraph,em,strong,hyperlink",
        "placeholder" : "Description..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as for now, prismic.io CMS doesn't allow required fields. The only required field is the native "UID" field. They recommend using the [in-website preview](https://prismic.io/docs/rest-api/beyond-the-api/the-preview-feature) for publishers to preview the result before shipping content rather than adding constraints in the editor.

Comment: Prismic platform is definitely fast to setup and has a slick UI but lacks some of the most BASIC features of a CMS.